# Add radial lines to radar chart

Tags: excel, excel-2013, radar-chart

I'm using Office 2013 Excel and making a radar chart.  By default the concentric rings are visible, but I want spokes or radial lines from the center to each category on the outside. I can't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Excel 2013 (and 2016).

A workaround is:

- Create a radar chart.
- Change the chart type to one of the other two radar charts, for e.g. radar with markers.
- Change the chart type back to the original radar chart and format the Y axis to have lines.

[image]

Comment: Spot on.  For clarification, right-click on the radius numbers > Format Axis,  Fill & Line > Line.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps that I follow to add radial lines:

- Create radar chart;
- Click on the radar chart to show the **Chart Design** tab on toolbar;
- Click on **Change Chart Type** and select Radar, then "Radar with
  Markers" or "Filled Radar";
- Click on **Add Chart Elements** (on the toolbar), then click on **Axes**, **More Axes Options...**;
- Click on **Fill & Line** icon (under the button "Axis Options"), find
  **Line** section and click on **Solid line**.

[image: Line]

Comment: This answer shows Excel for Mac. The question was about Excel 2013, which is NOT Excel for Mac. Question not addressed.

Answer (score 1):

How about the code below?

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).hasMajorGridlines=true
```

1. Select the target chart on excel.
2. Press Alt+F11 on excel, then VBE opens.
3. Press Ctrl+G on VBE, then immediate window opens.
4. Paste the above code.
5. Place the cursor on the line of the code and press the enter key.

I made the file with PHPExcel and edit it with excel 2010.

p.s. I confirmed with Excel 2016 without PHPExcel, too.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the rectangular edge of the overall chart.
Click "Chart Area" drop down.
Select "radar (value) axes" and click the pen icon to select a colour.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel for Mac version 16,
1. Create your radar chart.
2. Change chart type to any other chat type.
3. With your new chat selected. Go to Insert==>Chart==>Radar (the chart now allows you to format Y axis).