# Setting DoughnutHoleSize property smaller than 10

Tags: excel, vba

Excel allows the user to set the size of the hole in a doughnut chart between 0% and 90%. In VBA, the accepted range is 10% to 90%.

I can record a macro that produces this code:

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 0
```

However, it raises an error if I try to re-run it.  Is there another way to set the DoughnutHoleSize to a value less than 10 in VBA?  See the image below for the kind of plot I am trying to build.

[image: Combo dounghnut and scatter chart]

Comment: *it raises an error if I try to re-run it* - which error? Are you sure you have a chart object actually active when you re-run it? If so, is it the chart you think it is? Try assigning parentage and referencing the chart explicity instead of using `ActiveChart`?

Comment: It errors on the '.DoughnutHoleSize = 0'.  I have checked that the DoughnutHoleSize property exists and the above code works as expected with values between 10 and 90.  It only errors when I try to use a value less than 10. The ActiveChart/ChartGroups(1)/etc. is not causing any errors.

Comment: Things that make you go hmmm.... Wouldn't a doughnut hole chart with a hole size of 0 be a pie chart?

Comment: @xQbert, I should explain why I am using a doughnut chart! I am creating a polar plot and I am using the dounghnut chart for the gridlines.  I don't know of a way to do the gridlines with the pie chart.

Comment: Consider using a Radar chart instead? http://best-excel-tutorial.com/56-charts/262-polar-chart or a stack example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725844/add-radial-lines-to-radar-chart

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way of setting the DoughnutHoleSize to zero through VBA.

However, you can change just the inner-most series to a pie-chart. This will fill in the middle and keep the outer-series as Doughnuts.

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlPie